# Convert Crypto API calls to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cryptoapi

I have this code in C++ (AnsiString is a wrapper for char* buffer):

```
BOOL HashIt(AnsiString &pw,BYTE *buf,BYTE &len)
{
   HCRYPTPROV cp;
   CryptAcquireContext(&cp,NULL,NULL,PROV_RSA_AES,CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);

   HCRYPTHASH ch;
   CryptCreateHash(cp,CALG_MD5,0,0,&ch);

   CryptHashData(ch,(BYTE*)pw.c_str(),pw.Length(),0);

   HCRYPTKEY kc;
   CryptDeriveKey(cp,CALG_3DES,ch,CRYPT_EXPORTABLE,&kc);
   CryptExportKey(kc,NULL,PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB,0,buf,&dwLen);

   len = (BYTE) dwLen;
}
```

So far I've got this far converting it to .NET:

```
    public static byte[] HashItB(string text)
    {
        byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider sp = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] hashBytes = sp.ComputeHash(textBytes);
        System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes(hashBytes, new byte[0]);
        hashBytes = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, hashBytes);

        // Need to export key as plain text blob here, CryptExportKey

        return (hashBytes);
    }
```

Assuming the above code is correct, my last step is to translate the CryptExportKey function to .NET.  Can someone point me to the function or a sample?  I can't change the C++ method and I need my .NET code to match a legacy app.  Or should I give up on .NET methods and either create a C++ DLL and call that (not crazy about that due to extra size of shipping another DLL with my tiny app), or pinvoke all of the Crypto functions?

Comment: p.s.-the C++ code above has error checking and clean-up code removed, I do release all of those objects and check for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET method `PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey()` is the equivalent to using the Win32 CryptoAPI method to hash the password, call `CryptDeriveKey` and finally export the key by calling `CryptExportKey`.

Your C++-code is equivalent to:

```
byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text); // Default is the ANSI-code-page
System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes(textBytes, new byte[0]);
byte[] hashBytes = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "MD5", 0, new byte[8]);
```

except that the .NET-code removes some header data from the exported key (a PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB-header). For a 192 bit 3DES key this is `"08 02 00 00 03 66 00 00 18 00 00 00"`. You can just prepend it in the .NET-code if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

The PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey Method **already returns the derived key**, so there is no need to export a key as in your C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, and incase anyone needs this reading this post later, here is what I ended up with.  I'm sure the byte array building could be better, but in my case this code doesn't need to be fast so I just went with what was easy for me to read:

```
    public static byte[] HashIt(string text)
    {
        byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes(textBytes, new byte[0]);
        byte[] hashBytes = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "MD5", 0, new byte[8]);
        byte[] head = new byte[] { 0x08,0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        byte[] hashBytesWithHead = new byte[hashBytes.Length + head.Length];
        head.CopyTo(hashBytesWithHead,0);
        hashBytes.CopyTo(hashBytesWithHead,head.Length);
        return (hashBytesWithHead);
    }
```

Comment: Note that if `text` should ever contain non-ASCII characters, this will give a different result than the C++-code. This might not be a problem for you, but you should at least be aware of it.